# Make a Dynamic CSS grid when items descend on the left column first

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to design a CSS style where I have two columns and the items flow down the left hand column first before starting at the top of the right hand column. I can get this to work for a set number of items, but when I try to apply it to a dynamic lists where item's can be added and removed I either end up with a lop sided grid, or the data flows left to right. Essentially I to have items that go "A", "B", "C"... etc and I want it to look like this:

```
| A | F |
| B | G |
| C | H |
| D | I |
| E |
```

However, when I try various ways to make it dynamic it tends to either disrupt all the columns or the items flow as:

```
| A | B |
| C | D |
| E | F |
| G | H |
| I |
```

Which I do not want.

Here is a sample of the code I have been using if anyone has suggestions to create the result I require above.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(15, 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">A</div>
  <div class="grid-item">B</div>
  <div class="grid-item">C</div>
  <div class="grid-item">D</div>
  <div class="grid-item">E</div>
  <div class="grid-item">F</div>
  <div class="grid-item">G</div>
  <div class="grid-item">H</div>
  <div class="grid-item">I</div>
  <div class="grid-item">J</div>
  <div class="grid-item">K</div>
  <div class="grid-item">L</div>
  <div class="grid-item">M</div>
  <div class="grid-item">N</div>
  <div class="grid-item">O</div>
  <div class="grid-item">P</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Q</div>
  <div class="grid-item">R</div>
  <div class="grid-item">S</div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: are number of rows fixed ? how many rows can be there ?

Comment: Not possible without a defined number of rows or a fixed height AFAIK

Comment: If you don't need to use CSS-Grid you could use `column-count` I guess.